No option to install ubuntu alongside windows 10
I'm trying to install install dual boot windows and ubuntu 24.04.1 but it isn't detecting windows I can only erase the whole disk then install. I did some googling and I have turned off fast startup, made 100gb free space for ubuntu and disabled the secure boot but it still isn't giving the option for dual boot. I could really use some help with since I'm new to ubuntu.

Please indicate whether it boots in BIOS or UEFI mode

Start a live session of Ubuntu.
Once the boot is complete, open a terminal and run:
sudo apt install gparted
sudo gparted

From gparted, select the hard drive.
Unmount it if it is mounted.
Create a 50-gigabyte partition, ext4 system.
Create another 8-gigabyte partition, swap system.
Create another remaining partition that you plan to use for Linux, ext4 system.
Apply the changes, close gparted, close the terminal.
Start the installation.
Choose manual partitioning and select
Grub on the hard drive
The 50-gigabyte partition for /
The 8-gigabyte partition for swap
And the remaining one for /home.
Continue with the installation.

If drive has ESP - efi system partition from Windows this should work. But ESP required for UEFI boot.  And best that drive be gpt, not old MBR(msdos).  Microsoft requires gpt for UEFI boot, but Ubuntu does not.

Can you simplify it more for me so I don't get anything wrong then I'll try it. I have already made 100gb storage for ubuntu I have a pc with 1tb hard drive. Are you sure that after using gparted it will give the option to install alongside windows10

Theoretically, yes. Nothing can be said for sure. If you can't install, simply delete the partitions from gparted and you'll have the unpartitioned 100GB again.
